# I got the same adjusted p values (p adj) at different confidence levels (conf.level=0.95 and conf.level=0.90) when I run TukeyHSD in R

Tags: r, tukey-hsd-test

I am learning the TukeyHSD in R.  The following operations and results got me confused. I got the same adjusted p values at different confidence levels (0.90 and 0.95).  Should the adjusted p values are different at different confidence levels?

response variable
`size <- c(25,22,28,24,26,24,22,21,23,25,26,30,25,24,21,27,28,23,25,24,20,22,24,23,22,24,20,19,21,22)`

predictor variable
`location <- as.factor(c(rep("ForestA",10), rep("ForestB",10), rep("ForestC",10)))`

dataframe
`my.dataframe <- data.frame(size,location)`

Tukey HSD at 90% confidence level

`TukeyHSD(aov(size ~ location), conf.level=0.90)`

[image]

Tukey HSD at 95% confidence level

`TukeyHSD(aov(size ~ location), conf.level=0.95)`

[image]

Comment: Presumably because conf.level only affects the confidence interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adjusted $p$-value is not dependent upon the significance level, just like the ordinary $p$-value. You just compare these values to the significance level.  With ordinary $p$-values, you compare them to .05 or .01, or whatever your significance level (simple Type I error rate) is.  The choice of significance level does not change the $p$-value.

The same is true with adjusted $p$-values, with the exception that the significance level that you compare them to (.05 eg) now refers to Familywise Type I error rate.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what you are trying to do in R. But I don't think your problem lies there. Thing is, the p value tells you how likely your specific datapoints would have been, if the Hypothesis you are trying to disprove were true.

Comment: This generic reply doesn't address the specific circumstances of the question.

Comment: Let me ask the question in different way: When I ran TukeyHSD, the conf.level was set between 0 to 1 as the family-wise confidence level to use.  As I understand, the adjusted p values (p adj)  should be different as the conf.level changed.  However as the example I gave, the  adjusted p values kept the same as I changed the conf.level from 0.9 to 0.95.  Thanks